# Can twice a perfect square be divisible by $q^{\frac{q+1}{2}} + 1$, where $q$ is a prime with $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can twice a perfect square be divisible by

$$q^{\frac{q+1}{2}} + 1,$$

where $q$ is a prime with $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Comment: Isn't that number even?

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed that particular detail.  I actually meant to ask: "Can twice a perfect square be divisible by $\ldots$?".

Comment: @Inceptio, can you still edit your answer?  I apologize, I am unsure on how we can proceed.  (I am a bit unfamiliar with how Math@StackExchange works - I only know how to do the LaTeX part.)

Comment: @ArnieB.Dris: Never mind. I will **TRY** getting another solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

$q \equiv 1 \mod 4 \implies q^{\frac{q+1}{2}} + 1 \equiv 2 \mod 4$

$q^{\frac{q+1}{2}} + 1 =(2k+1)2$

Twice of $(2k+1)^2$ is divisible by $q^{\frac{q+1}{2}}+1$. Maybe you can write $k$ in terms of $q$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer @Inceptio.  I apologize, but I think I was in the process of editing my question (in response to JonasMeyer's comment) while you were writing down this answer.

Comment: @ArnieB.Dris: Is this a part of a question or the actual question itself?

Comment: Thanks @Inceptio, it's an actual question :)

Comment: So it means that the condition will only work for odd perfect squares, then?  :)

Comment: @ArnieB.Dris: Yes, but only which satisfy the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Try proving something "harder":

**Theorem:** Let $n$ be a positive integer. There exists a positive integer $k$ such that $n | 2k^2$

> k=n

Comment: **Easier** to **Harder**? ;)

Comment: Yah. Harder, in scare quotes, was what I meant. This is a more general theorem, so in principle it *should* be harder. But really the generalization simply brushes away all of the obfuscating detail which makes it easier to see the solution without being sidetracked.

Comment: Thanks @Hurkyl.  I do get your point.  :)